# How to open "Network Connections/Ethernet/Properties"?

Tags: c#, networking, ip

I can open the network connections window with

```
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("NCPA.cpl");
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            Process.Start(startInfo);
```

but can i somehow open a specific network card properties to change its ip address?
Basically i want to go to "Network Connections/Ethernet/Properties/TCP/IPv4" menu to quickly change IP address.

Comment: [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/735292/how-to-open-tcp-ip-properties-from-cmd-or-run-directly) suggests that it's not posisble. Unless Windows 10 has changed something, that is. The bigger question (which they also seem to answer) is _why?_ Just set the new IP address programmatically.

Comment: If you're desperate to use Process.Start, you probably wouldn't open a UI and programmatically use it when there is a [command line way](https://www.howtogeek.com/103190/CHANGE-YOUR-IP-ADDRESS-FROM-THE-COMMAND-PROMPT/) of performing the same actions

Comment: It should be something like (in ProcessStartInfo): `UseShellExecute = true, FileName = "rundll32.exe", Arguments = "shell32.dll, Control_RunDLL NCPA.cpl,,0"`. The last `0` defines the tab index of a tabbed Window. I'm sure I've used it with `timedate.cpl` (but cannot test it right now). -- To change the IPAddress programmatically, you can use WMI, it's the `EnableStatic` method of the `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` class.